# Python multiprocessing library thinks multilettered args are multiple args

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Ive been trying to program this piece of code that analsizes stocks and whenenver i try to pass a stock symbol such as "GOOG" trought multiproccess it takes each letter of "GOOG" as a different argument.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def main():
    for value in stocks:
        
        p = mp.Process(target=nnfuncs.compare, args=value["symbol"])
        
        p.start()
        nnstruct.processes.append(p) 
        
    for process in nnstruct.processes:
        process.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The "stocks" var contains "AWP" "ACP" "JEQ" "ASGI" "AOD".

If i were to run that it would tell me that "TypeError: compare() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were give" even though those are all one arguments, it multiproccesing takes it as each letter of the symbol is one different argument.

Comment: `args` is expected to contain a list of arguments, not just one argument -- that's why it's called "args", not "arg". When you interpret a string as a list, each character becomes a separate element.

Comment: A minimal working example helps. You could create an worker function that just prints its arguments and use a canned example for the Process class. Then we can all run it, and as important, its the basic for a complete working example in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `args` parameter in `multiprocessing.Process` are interpreted as a tuple (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class)), so your text arguments are being interpreted as `tuple("AWP") == ("A", "W", "P")`. You probably want to pass your argument as `args=(value["symbol"],)`.